# Change JSON output on MVC 5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, datatable

I'm integrating my Model's json output with [datatables](http://datatables.net) in JavaScript.

The datatables expects:

```
{
   "draw":1,
   "recordsTotal":57,
   "recordsFiltered":57,
   "data":[
      [
         "Airi",
         "Satou",
         "Accountant",
         "Tokyo",
         "28th Nov 08",
         "$162,700"
      ],
      [
         "Airi",
         "Satou",
         "Accountant",
         "Tokyo",
         "28th Nov 08",
         "$162,700"
      ],...
   ]
}
```

But my Model renders:

```
[
   {
      "Column1":"data",
      "Column2":"data",
      "Column3":"data",
      "Column4":"data",
      "Column5":"data"
   },
   {
      "Column1":"data",
      "Column2":"data",
      "Column3":"data",
      "Column4":"data",
      "Column5":"data"
   },...
]
```

My model is defined as:

```
Public Class DataForAJAX
    Public Property Column1() As String
    Public Property Column2() As String
    Public Property Column3() As String
    Public Property Column4() As String
    Public Property Column5() As String

End Class
```

And I use Dapper to load an IEnumerable(Of DataForAjax)

Is there anyway to output exactly what I want for the datatables? As you might have noted, I'm looking at the data node in the json for datatables specifically, but would love to populate number of records as well. Somehow I can't figure this out. If it was PHP or Classic ASP I'd have generated this easy :)

Thanks for any constructive help in pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Create a DTO class that is modeled after the format you want the data in, i.e. create property names and hierarchies just as in the output JSON you desire. Then, either manually map your model to this class, or use something like AutoMapper to automate the process and send your DTO back as the result instead.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I did try what you suggested but my attempts didn't really get the format I wanted. What would you suggest?

Comment: Thanks Chris, your comment has helped me in the right direction, I upvoted this, but will add the answer (of the modified model) too

Answer (score 0):

I took what Chriss Pratt said and played around a LOT more with what I tried to do initially. In the end I created a container model:

```
Public Class DataForAJAXContainer
   Public Property recordsTotal() as Integer
   Public Property recordsFilteredTotal() as Integer
   Public Property draw() as Integer
   Public Property data() as List(Of List(Of String))
End Class
```

And then I create a list item, and loop through my database results and add each column to the list

```
Dim l as New List
l.Add(Column1)
l.Add(Column2)
l.Add(Column3)
l.Add(Column4)
l.Add(Column5)
```

Then I add it to my container model

```
Dim c as New DataForAJAXContainer
c.data.Add(l)
```

This all happens in the loop through each DataForAJAX objects.

The result of the JSON output for the model is then in the format expected by datatables.

If anyone has a better/cleaner solution, it'd be awesome to hear and learn